# Need help on building a function that creates a new edition nft from a master edition nft

Tags: rust, solana, nft, metaplex, anchor-solana

[image link to my code]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWtpj.png

I am currently writing a Solana Metaplex NFT program in Rust/Anchor-Solana, specifically working on writing a logic to create a edition NFT from a master edition NFT.

While invoking `mpl_token_metadata::instruction::mint_new_edition_from_master_edition_via_token` instruction, I found out that it requires both `metadata` and `metadata_mint` field as arguments. Whereas, on the metaplex documentation, it seems the instruction only requires the Master record metadata account.

**Question:**

Which account key, or value, should I put in to each of those fields(`metadata` and `metadata_mint`) and why?

**Code:**

```
pub fn create_new_edition_nft(
        ctx: Context<CreateNewEdition>,
        edition: u64,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let edition_infos = vec![
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.new_metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.new_edition.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.new_mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.new_mint_authority.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_account_owner.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.new_metadata_update_authority.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        ];
        msg!("Edition Account Infos Assigned");
        invoke(&mint_new_edition_from_master_edition_via_token(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.key(),ctx.accounts.new_metadata.key(),ctx.accounts.new_edition.key(), ctx.accounts.master_edition.key(), ctx.accounts.new_mint.key(),ctx.accounts.new_mint_authority.key(), ctx.accounts.payer.key(), ctx.accounts.token_account_owner.key(), ctx.accounts.token_account.key(), ctx.accounts.new_metadata_update_authority.key(), ctx.accounts.metadata.key(), ctx.accounts.metadata.key(), edition
        ), edition_infos.as_slice())?;

        msg!("A New Edition Nft Minted !!!");
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateNewEdition<'info> {
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_edition: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub master_edition: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_mint: UncheckedAccount<'info>,    
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub edition_mark_pda: UncheckedAccount<'info>,    
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_mint_authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: AccountInfo<'info>,
    // /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account_owner: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    // /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_metadata_update_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,    
    // #[account(mut)]
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    pub rent: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

**Documentation Reference:**

Documentation for printing a new edition from a master edition:

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#print-a-new-edition-from-a-master-edition

Comment: Only your comments have the field `metadata_mint`, which field or argument do you mean?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of it. You can see the field metadata_mint from this pic. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWtpj.png

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on metaplex you are talking about is the documentation of the solana instructions but not the rust api. They are different. If you take a look at the rust code, you will see the differences.

The accounts described in the documentation match the accounts provided by the code:

```
let accounts = vec![
   AccountMeta::new(new_metadata, false),
   AccountMeta::new(new_edition, false),
   AccountMeta::new(master_edition, false),
   AccountMeta::new(new_mint, false),
   AccountMeta::new(edition_mark_pda, false),
   AccountMeta::new_readonly(new_mint_authority, true),
   AccountMeta::new(payer, true),
   AccountMeta::new_readonly(token_account_owner, true),
   AccountMeta::new_readonly(token_account, false),
   AccountMeta::new_readonly(new_metadata_update_authority, false),
   AccountMeta::new_readonly(metadata, false),
   AccountMeta::new_readonly(spl_token::id(), false),
   AccountMeta::new_readonly(solana_program::system_program::id(), false),
   AccountMeta::new_readonly(sysvar::rent::id(), false),
];
```

The variable `metadata_mint` you are talking about is used to calculate the address of the `edition_mark_pda` address on chain:

```
    let (edition_mark_pda, _) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[
            PREFIX.as_bytes(),
            program_id.as_ref(),
            metadata_mint.as_ref(),
            EDITION.as_bytes(),
            as_string.as_bytes(),
        ],
        &program_id,
    );
```

When you compare this with the documentation, you will see what should be provided:

> Edition pda to mark creation - will be checked for pre-existence. (pda
> of ['metadata', program id, master metadata mint id, 'edition',
> edition_number]) where edition_number is NOT the edition number you
> pass in args but actually edition_number =
> floor(edition/EDITION_MARKER_BIT_SIZE).

`metadata` := Master record metadata account

`metadata_mint` := master metadata mint id

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Btw, I am still a bit confused... I get that metadata mint id is used to calculate an Edition Mark PDA, but still don't get what master metadata mint id is referring to. Is it the metadata account of the master edition account? or just the mint account of the master edition account? or else

Comment: Oh I think I get it. It's just a original mint account id. Then, within my rust function above, how can I retrieve that mint account id? I mean I don't see the original mint account among the list of accounts required for the instruction, so should I derive it from somewhere or can I access that value from some object? plz let me know @AlexN

Comment: You can take a look at the documentation you provided it shows the relation between the `metadata_mint` and the `metadata`. From the `metadata_mint` you can compute the `metadata` but not the other way around. https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#create-a-metadata-account + https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#create-a-master-edition-account

Comment: Yeah I get that part, but amongst the list of accounts described on the documentation there is no field for the original mint account while the mint_new_edition_from_master_edition_via_token instruction requires it. Should I just simply add the original mint account in the list or simply pass that as a argument or sth? @AlexN